# How do I access one array element at a time using pointer to a character array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

So, in the code below what I'm trying to do is find `subArr` in `arr`. But as you can see that I'm not able to use the `for` loop properly so that I can then start comparing.
What should I take as the satisfying condition to access each character of that array element (say: `cream` at position `0`) at the respective position?
And then compare it with `subArr` character by character to see if `subArr` exists in `arr`
My ultimate goal is to find out if `subArr` exists in `arr`. if it does then `return 1`, else `return 0`

I'm not to use `strstr()`.

```
int myStrStr (char * arr, char * subArr, char * buffer) {
// printf("%s\n", arr);
// printf("%s\n", subArr);
// printf("%s", buffer = subArr);

int count = 0;

for(int i = 0; arr[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    //for(int j = 0; needle[j] != '\0'; j++) {
    if(arr[i] == subArr[i]) {
    buffer[count] = arr[i];
    count++;
    printf("Array: %c\n", arr[i]);
    printf("SubArray: %c\n", subArr[j]);
    //printf("%s", buffer = subArr);
    //}
}
//printf("\nBuffer: %s\n",buffer);
int result = strcmp(buffer, needle);
if(result == 0) {
    return 1;
} else {
    return 0;
}
} 

int main() {
    char arr[][10] = {"cream","factory","camel","crosses","eating","cake"};
    char subArr[][10] = {"cream","at","am","cross","in","kk"};
    char buffer[160];

    int answer1 = myStrStr(arr[0],subArr[0], buffer);
    int answer2 = myStrStr(arr[1],subArr[1], buffer);
    int answer3 = myStrStr(arr[2],subArr[2], buffer);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are `needle` and `haystack` arrays?

Comment: In any string example `str` the index used to traverse is never equal to `\0` itself but the value `str[index]` might be `\0` - check the `for` loops.

Comment: @Observer Fixed the names of arrays (`arr` and `subArr`).

Comment: @Observer `for(int i = 0; arr[i] != '\0'; i++) {}` this is what you mean by that, right?

Comment: @melpomene I believe that doesn't have any effects on what I'm trying to achieve. But thanks for the correction.

Comment: You've changed the code so the bit you're asking about (`for(; i != '\0'; )`) doesn't appear anywhere. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @melpomene I apologize, I've updated my logic and description as I'm currently trying to solve the problem too and getting updates in it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple (rough) example to clarify the things:

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 int num;                        //SECOND DIMENSION OF THE 2D ARRAY

 void fun(char c[][num])
 {
     for(int i=0;c[i][0]!='\0';++i)   
         printf("%s\n",c[i]);      //c[i] MEANS STRING AT Ith INDEX, C[2] = "XYZ"
 }

 int main(void)
 {
     char c[][10]={"hello","world","xyz"};
     num = sizeof(c[0]);              //NO. OS SEPARATE STRINGS POSSIBLE
     fun(c);
     return 0;
 }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
hello
world
xyz
```

In the function `fun` when we say `c[i]` then we are accessing **string** present at **i**th index, example `c[1]` in above example is `world` - now if you want to compare elements of two arrays of arrays then you can access each string index by index and use `strcmp`, example:

```
strcmp(subArr[j],arr[i])
```

Both `subArr[0]` and `arr[0]` are same i.e. `cream` in the question, hence when we use `strcmp` it will return **0** indicating that both `subArr[0]` and `arr[0]` are same.

Comment: That makes sense. I get what you're trying to explain, but still, I'm getting confused with using pointer to char arrays, here in the problem I've to access one array element at a time and then check if `subArr` exists in it. if it does then return 1. And then check for the next element. Does that makes it more clear?

Comment: @RajatGupta Now with the above example I hope you understand that you can access entire string at a time and then to compare them you just need `strcmp` function which is part of `string.h` header. Plus you shouldn't return if the two strings are exactly the same - you should just store `1` in some array to signify that string at index `i` is present in second array as well.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but before using `strcmp`. I've to see if `arr` even has `subArr` in it or not. This is where my logic is failing.

Comment: @RajatGupta Edited the answer